# Custom Emacs key bindings are not working

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

The key bindings I've defined in my `.emacs` file aren't working. Here's the file:

```
;init modes
(menu-bar-mode 0)
(tool-bar-mode 0)
(cua-mode)
(column-number-mode)
(fset 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)
(cperl-set-style PerlStyle)

;keymappings
(global-set-key [f12] 'save-buffer)
(global-set-key [S-f12] 'write-file)
(global-set-key [f7] 'ispell)
(global-set-key [up] 'scroll-one-line-up)
(global-set-key [down] 'scroll-one-line-down)

;functions
(defun scroll-one-line-up (&optional arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (scroll-up (or arg 1)))
(defun scroll-one-line-down (&optional arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (scroll-down (or arg 1)))
```

I know Emacs parses the file since everything else seems to work. It's just that the keys are not being bound.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Jari Aalto has an excellent (and exhaustive) guide to binding keys: http://www.nongnu.org/emacs-tiny-tools/keybindings/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an error in your `.emacs` at line:

```
(cperl-set-style PerlStyle)
```

It should be written as:

```
(cperl-set-style 'PerlStyle)
```

Since it raises an error that stops parsing `.emacs` at that point, your key bindings won't be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks Török, although the problem wasn't quite that.  The cperl-set-style function only exists if cperl-mode has been run.  So that was the line that is giving me a parsing error.  Do you happen to know a good reference on how to run functions conditionally with respect to the mode?

Comment: @gvkv: You're looking for mode hooks.  See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeHooks for more info.  Something like this should do the trick: (add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook (lambda () (cperl-set-style 'PerlStyle)))

Comment: Also, `emacs --debug-init` would help diagnose this.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what your problem might be without more information, like is it all your keybindings or just one or two that do not work.  I will hazard a guess that it is the last two ([up] and [down]).  In those cases the on-line documentation below seems to indicate that you might be shadowing the global definitions with local ones defined by the mode.

> global-set-key is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `subr.el'.
>
> `(global-set-key key command)`
>
> Give key a global binding as command.
>   command is the command definition to
>   use; usually it is a symbol naming an
>   interactively-callable function. key
>   is a key sequence; noninteractively,
>   it is a string or vector of characters
>   or event types, and non-ASCII
>   characters with codes above 127 (such
>   as ISO Latin-1) can be included if you
>   use a vector.
>
> Note that if key has a local binding
>   in the current buffer, that local
>   binding will continue to shadow any
>   global binding that you make with this
>   function.

Comment: I don't think that the local mapping is the problem since C-h k <F12>, for example, returns "<F12> is undefined".  If by chance it is, however, what do I do about it?

Comment: You would have to change the binding in the local keymap using a hook variable.  Here's an example that I use with java-mode:

(defun java-setup ()
  (setq tab-stop-list
        '(4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76 80 84 88 92)
        indent-tabs-mode nil
        tab-width 4
 fill-column 96
        c-comment-start-regexp "\\(@\\|/\\(/\\|[*][*]?\\)\\)"))

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'java-setup)

In your case you would use something like:

(defun mysetup ()
  (define-key local-map [f12] 'func))

(add-hook 'your-mode-hook 'mysetup)

Comment: That was a bad idea.  I'll redo my comment as another answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up to my previous answer, you would have to change the binding in the local keymap using a hook variable. Here's an example that I use with java-mode:

```
(defun java-setup ()
   (setq tab-stop-list '(4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76 80 84 88 92)
         indent-tabs-mode nil
         tab-width 4
         fill-column 96
         c-comment-start-regexp "\\(@\\|/\\(/\\|[*][*]?\\)\\)"))

 (add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'java-setup)
```

In your case you would use something like:

```
 (defun mysetup ()
    (define-key local-map [f12] 'func))

 (add-hook 'your-mode-hook 'mysetup)
```

Also, fwiw, I do the following to define my global keys:

```
(defun function-key-help ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "*Help*")
  (erase-buffer)
  (insert-file (expand-file-name "~/lib/fkeys.help"))
  (message "Type C-x b <nl> to remove help window."))

(define-key global-map [f12] 'function-key-help)
```

And it works perfectly in my Emacs 23 setup.

Comment: Thanks for the quickie tutorial.  I'm going to try this tonight.